# Modifying name of company of app after approval

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, ipod, appstore-approval

Today my app is ready for sale on app store but unfortunately I made a mistake when providing my company name. Is there any way to modify the company name? If anyone has any idea then please share.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you want to change it in the source code files..?

Comment: no actually i want to modify it on app store

Comment: What on earth is a mail main?

Comment: well i think he will have to edit it so please give me idea how should i solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

The company name is set permanently when you submit your first app. You cannot change it once your app has been submitted. You should've been more careful. Read the docs which clearly state this. Your best bet now is to contact Apple and see what can be done.

Comment: ok i think i should call their customer care since i am not getting anything from manage your application part to solve my problem from itunes connect.But can you guess whether it will be posiible

Comment: I clearly mentioned it. You cannot change it. The last resort is to call/mail them and state your case.

Comment: can you please guide me where to call and mail since i am stuck and not getting perfect number or email for such scenarios .

Answer (score 0):

At Last i came to know after calling apple developer support that it's one time setting for PERSONAL ACCOUNT and can not be changed only we can edit the company name to seller name .We can not make any other change So please be careful while submitting your first app.And if your account is COMPANY ACCOUNT in that case it's possible by following some tedious procedures.As my account was personal account so i left it as it was by taking a lesson.Thanks to all who guided me in the process.